# MySQL: How to make select and delete in the same table in single query?

Tags: mysql

How to make select and delete in the same table in single query?

When I try:

```
DELETE
FROM comment
WHERE comment_id =
(select comment_id from comment where parent_id = 0 group by autor_id, user_id, resource_id, comment_body HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

I get an error: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'comment' for update in FROM clause

```
WHERE comment_id IN
```

send me the same error

Note: I cant use 2 different query because I want use it in the Event Scheduler

Comment: Your query doesnt' make any sense. You can't group by fields and have your primary key in your select. What are you trying to achieve? It seems like you want to delete comments based on some condition. What is that condition? Is comment_id unique?

Comment: You can go around the error: #1093 by wrapping your subquery in a `SELECT FROM (SELECT ...)` a few times, but the entire thing looks a bit wrong to me...

Comment: I try to delete the same comment posted by the sme person. So, duble comments. select comment_id from comment where parent_id = 0 group by autor_id, user_id, resource_id, comment_body HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 return me comment ID which I want to remove

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you going.

```
DELETE 
  c
FROM 
  comment c

  inner join (
    # some select statement that pulls all of your required comments
  ) comment_to_delete on
    comment_to_delete.comment_id = c.comment_id
```

Sorry not really following what you are trying to do in your code